# Applying literal_eval on string of lists of POS tags gives ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

In a pandas column I have list of POS tags as string. I thought this must be string because `print(dataset['text_posTagged'][0][0])` prints `[`.

> dataset['text_posTagged']

```
['VBP', 'JJ', 'NNS', 'VBP', 'JJ', 'IN', 'PRP', 'VBP', 'TO', 'VB', 'PRP', 'RB', 'VBZ', 'DT', 'JJ', 'PRP$', 'NN', 'NN', 'NN', 'NN', 'VBZ', 'JJ']
['UH', 'DT', 'VB', 'VB', 'PRP$', 'NN', 'TO', 'JJ', 'IN', 'PRP', 'MD', 'VB', 'DT', 'VBZ', 'DT', 'NN', 'NN']
['NN', 'VBD', 'NN', 'NN', 'NN', 'DT', 'IN', 'IN', 'NN', 'IN', 'NN', 'NN', 'VBD', 'IN', 'JJ', 'NN', 'NN']
```

To convert this to an actual list I used the following.

```
dataset['text_posTagged'] = dataset.text_posTagged.apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x)).
```

However, this gives **ValueError: malformed node or string: nan**

When I applied the same in a column that has list of words, it works fine.

> dataset['text']

```
['are', 'red', 'violets', 'are', 'blue', 'if', 'you', 'want', 'to', 'buy', 'us', 'here', 'is', 'a', 'clue', 'our', 'eye', 'amp', 'cheek', 'palette', 'is', 'al']
['is', 'it', 'too', 'late', 'now', 'to', 'say', 'sorry']
['our', 'amazonian', 'clay', 'full', 'coverage', 'foundation', 'comes', 'in', '40', 'shades', 'of', 'creamy', 'goodness']
```

The following prints `are`

```
dataset['text'] = dataset.text.apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x)).
print(dataset['text'][0][0])
```

**What is wrong with applying literal_eval on list of POS tags?** How to do it properly?

Comment: "I thought this must be string because `print(dataset['text_posTagged'][0][0])` prints `[`. " This result is **also** consistent with a **sequence of** strings (list, tuple etc.). If it is actually just a string, then `print(dataset['text_posTagged'][0])` would **also** print `[`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse only non-null rows. You can drop the lambda.

```
m = dataset['text_posTagged'].notna()
dataset.loc[m, 'text_posTagged'] = (
    dataset.loc[m, 'text_posTagged'].apply(literal_eval))
```

If you have 100 rows or fewer, you can also use `pd.eval`:

```
dataset.loc[m, 'text_posTagged'] = pd.eval(dataset.loc[m, 'text_posTagged'])
```